# jQuery slider with tabs to animate the slider

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to add some tabs to add more usability to a jQuery slider. I managed to add some tabs based on how many slides there are in the HTML. Now if I click on one of these tabs (1, 2, 3, 4) it will have to bring me to the related slide any ideas of directions on how to achieve this please?

This is what I have so far:

```
 var slides = $('.slide');
 var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

function createTabs() {  // creates tabs based on how many slides in HTML
for (i = 1; i < numberOfSlides + 1; i++) {
    $('#tabsstyle').append('<p>' + i + '</p>')
}
}
createTabs();
$("#tabsstyle p").click(function () {
// here the code to jump on the related slide
})
```

Let me know if you need more info.
Thanks

Added HTML

```
<div id="pageContainer">
<!-- Slideshow HTML -->
<div id="slideshow">

<div id="slidesContainer">

  <div id="one" class="slide">
    <h2></h2>
    </div>

  <div id="two" class="slide">
    <h2></h2>
     </div>

  <div id="three" class="slide">
    <h2></h2>
   </div>

  <div id="four" class="slide">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>


</div>
<div id="tabsstyle"></div>
```

Comment: Please post you HTML, we can hardly guess `#tabsstyle` and `p`...

Comment: Its better if you can change the ids of slide from 'one', 'two' to numeric values like '1','2'. In this case my answer will work.

Comment: I have edited my answer to suit your needs. Please see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information provided by you, I think this can help. Although it may not be 100% correct, but it can give you some idea.

```
$("#tabsstyle p").click(function () {
   var index = $(this).index();
   $('#slidesContainer').find('.slide').hide();
   $('#tabsstyle').find('p').each(function(pos){
      var slideToShow = parseInt(pos) + 1;
      if(pos == index){
          $('#slidesContainer').find('.slide:nth-child('+slideToShow+')').show();
      }
   });
})
```